# Custom state-enter and state-exit code with routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a fairly simple Angular project which routes to a couple different URLs in the JavaScript:

```
function RootController($scope) {};

function PageOneController($scope) {};

angular.module('mymodule', []).config(
    ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
             templateUrl: "templates/root.html",
             controller: RootController
        }).when('/page1/', {
             templateUrl: "templates/page1.html",
             controller: PageOneController
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]
);
```

Everything works great so far, but I do need a way to have some JavaScript function run on when these routes are entered and exited. ie:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
     templateUrl: "templates/root.html",
     controller: RootController,
     onenter: function() { console.log("Enter!"); },
     onexit: function() { console.log("Exit!"); }
 });
```

Is there a way to do this in Angular? On enter of a state/route, I need to bind event listeners, and on exit I need to destroy them and tear down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[$route service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) has two events `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess`, these can be of some help for you.

You can use `$routeChangeStart` before exiting and `$routeChangeSuccess` on entering.

You can do `$scope.$on` on any controller to watch for these events.